# How to pass a value of java script variable in the rel attribute of anchor

Tags: javascript, html

This is a very basic and silly question but i am facing this problem since a long and now it has confused me :(

I am trying to pass a javascript variable value as a querystring parameter in the rel attribute of the anchor tag. But some how I am not able to pass the value.

Here is my code.

```
this.pid = pid;
console.log('here is pid'+this.pid); // I am getting correct value here.
var formattedUrl = "<a rel=EProgramDetail?programid='+pid+'&format=SD>" +  value + "</a>" ;
```

but onclicking of the url, it gives me an error but if i hardcode the value, it runs fine.

Please help.

Regards
Hp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the syntax highlighting demonstrates, you're mixing up your quotes:

```
var formattedUrl = "<a rel=EProgramDetail?programid=" + pid + "&format=SD>" +  value + "</a>" ;
```

Since you started the string with double quotes, you need to end it with double quotes. Single quotes will be treated as a literal single quote, part of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Your single and double quotes aren't matching up.

Try this:

```
var formattedUrl = "<a rel='EProgramDetail?programid=" + pid + "&format=SD'>" +  value + "</a>" ;
```